# Sync Google Calendar with Outlook 2007 Calendar

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2007, google-calendar

What's a good way to sync Google Calendar with Outlook Calendar 2007?

I need to do this so I can sync my calendar with my iPod via iTunes

Also, how can I repeat an event in Outlook Calendar 2007?

So, basically I need to sync my Google Calendar, but I need to make sure my Google Calendar events are still set to repeat in Outlook Calendar

Comment: Nice question by the way!

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little "Tuto" on how to do this.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook/HA101674951033.aspx

I tried it and I found one bug. Whenever you add your calendar into MS Outlook 2007 and sync into Google Calendar, Reminder is set top at 15 minuets.

My Default Reminder already set as Email - 10 Min. and SMS - 10 MIN. so you have to change reminder manually in every event which you added into MS Outlook.

It works well tho... Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to sync your Google Calendar with your iPhone, you may be better served by using the iPhone's built-in Exchange support directly instead of going through Outlook.  Google provides instructions for this here: http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740&topic=14252.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link: http://www.google.com/sync/pc.html

This will sync all of your Google Calendar with Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sync is great and works well BUT it only works with Google Apps Premier version (not the free Google Apps Standard).  Google Apps Premier is $50 per user per year.

So, as long as you are ok with the cost you are ok.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this free and opensource tool: Go Contact Sync Mod (http://sourceforge.net/projects/googlesyncmod/) since 2011.
The new version adds Calendar sync, just in time when Google has sunset its own Google Calendar Sync.