# How can I sync Google and Outlook 2007 calendars on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sync, microsoft-outlook-2007, google-calendar

very similar to: [Sync Google Calendar with Outlook 2007 Calendar](https://superuser.com/questions/111095/sync-google-calendar-with-oulook-calendar-2007)

But with one caveat. I'm running Windows 7 and Google Calendar Sync is not compatible. Any ideas on how I can sync my Google and Outlook 2007 calendars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**OggSync**](http://oggsync.com/) is free if you want to sync only 1 Google calendar with Outlook 2007 (and 2003 and 2010). It works in both directions.

> - Full 2 Way Sync (Settable for each Google Calendar)
> - One way sync (Outlook/Mobile to Google and Google to Outlook/Mobile,
>     settable for each Google Calendar)
> - Support for Default Calendar (Support for unknown Outlook
>     Categories to Default Calendar)
> - Support for Multiple Google Calendars and Multiple Outlook
>     Calendars
> - Ability to enter new events into any Google Calendar in OggSync Mobile
> - Supports Google’s brand new multiple reminder settings. (2 way
>     sync with outlook/device for closest
>     pop-up appointment.)
> - Publish only Free/Busy Info (from Google or from Outlook/Mobile and
>     Individually Settable by each Google
>     Calendar)
> - Always Free Option (Individually Settable for each Google Calendar)
> - Do Not Publish Private Events (Individually Settable for each Google
>     Calendar)
> - No Reminders Option (Individually Settable for each Google Calendar)
> - Import Google Colors into Outlook 2003
> - Google Calendars mapped to Outlook Categories (Category Colors settable
>     in Outlook 2007) XP and Vista
>     Supported
> - Auto Sync Feature in both Outlook and Mobile
> - One Subscription Per Google Account (Use Outlook and Mobile versions of
>     OggSync for the same subscription)

If you want to synchronize several calendars or need more advanced options, the Pro version is 29.95$.

Comment: I really want this to work, but I'm getting a error when trying to open after the installation.
---------------------------
OggSync Startup Encountered an Exception:  Unable to cast COM object of type  (followed by a reference to QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}' failed due the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)). at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass.get_Application() at b..ctor()

Comment: I've accepted this answer, as it should work. I'm having issues on the install.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could try out [gSyncit](http://www.daveswebsite.com/software/gsync/). I can confirm it works on Windows 7 x64, and it already supports both flavours (x32 and x64) of Outlook 2010.

> Features
>
> - Outlook 2010 32-bit and 64-bit support
> - Sync Outlook notes, calendars, tasks, and contacts with Google services.
> - Synchronize multiple Outlook calendars, contacts, tasks, and notes folders with Google services.
> - Synchronize and filter Gmail contacts using Gmail groups and Outlook categories.
> - Synchronize contacts, calendars, task, and notes using Outlook categories.
> - Automatically matches entries to reduce duplicates entries from being created.
> - Supports configurations for different Outlook profiles.
> - Secure sync and tons of other options.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google doesn't seem to care about supporting sync with MS Outlook any more. I have been waiting for many months for a release that would be compatible with Outlook 64 bit but they have yet to release it.

Out of exasperation I asked a programmer to develop a software to do such a thing. It will be distributed Freeware, donations will hopefully keep the project running

At the moment we just released the first beta version. It can be downloaded at the blog I have created for the purpose at 
http://outlook-google-sync.blogspot.com/
For comments and feedbacks please use the following forum
http://outlook-googlesync.forumfree.it/