# Sync google calendar and contacts with Outlook 10

Tags: gmail, sync, google-calendar, microsoft-outlook-2010, google-contacts

I use a google accounts for mail/contacts/calendar. I use Outlook 2010 on my desktop and an iphone. Iphone syncs calendar/contacts/mail via what I presume is faux exchange mechanism, anyway it works.

Mail obviously works in Outlook using IMAP. I used to get calendar sync using google calendar sync - however this does not support Outlook 2010. Given this is something Google have been alerted to since 2009 - I presume they have no plans to fix it.

Is there a solution here? Can I make Outlook 2010 sync in a similair way to how my iphone works (using m.gmail.com ?). Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [gSyncit](http://www.daveswebsite.com/software/gsync/) instead. It costs $15.

However, it:

- supports Outook 2003, 2007, 2010
- Can sync to Multiple Google accounts (including Google Apps for domain accounts)
- Can sync not only contacts, but also calendar, tasks etc.
- Is actively supported by the developer, unlike Google Calendar Sync (which is suffering from bit-rot)

I used to be a Google Calendar Sync user myself, until about a year back, when I got tired of the buggy software and switched to gSyncit instead.

Comment: I also use gSyncit, main point is that it supports Outlook 2010 x64 for which I don't think there's any alternative solution

Comment: so many other microsoft/apple/google services integrate so seamlessly nowadays that I find it mind boggling that I have to use a (potentially non secure) third party app for this. How can two of the top companies in this field, that pride themselves on their secure technology, let this happen? Having said that, gsyncit works great.

Answer (score 0):

As per the GMail Blog,

> Google Calendar Sync now supports Outlook 2010 — our top feature
>   request. Outlook 2010 comes in 32-bit and 64-bit versions, and
>   currently only 32-bit is supported. To start syncing your calendar
>   with Outlook 2010, download Google Calendar Sync version 0.9.3.6. Once
>   you install it, a Settings window will appear. Enter your account’s
>   email address and password, choose your sync option and sync
>   frequency, and you’re done! (Note: If you’re already using Google
>   Calendar Sync, you’ll still need to download and install this new
>   version in order to be able to sync with Outlook 2010. If you need
>   help, take a look at our [getting started guide.](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=89955))

Comment: This is useful (although I can't seem to get it to work) but the problem is it's only 1 way - outlook consuming the web service as opposed to a 2 way sync.

http://blog.sublogic.com/2010/03/08/getting-google-calendar-sync-to-work-with-outlook-2010/ would have been perfect, but it seems this does not work with 64bit Outlook - which is why I presume Google have gone back to the drawing board on their the sync system.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, as they lose all value when the linked web page is no longer available. Please include the gist of the solution in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.psencik.simple

I've tried a dozen solutions and this is my favorite by far.  I'm using it with Outlook 2013 x64

Answer (score 0):

I use Go Contact Sync Mod since 2011 to have wireless, unattended, 2-way Outlook-Cloud-Phone sync.
See more details here: https://superuser.com/a/803499/61033